# Como declarar el tamaño de la matriz y después ingresar dato por dato?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, matrices

de nuevo pidiendo su ayuda, me encuentro haciendo un programa que el usuario ingrese el tamaño de la matriz, esta no debe de sobrepasar 16, entonces despues quiero rellenar espacio por espacio numeros menores a 600 y mayores a 200, como lo logro hacer? Aqui un espacio de mi codigo:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de filas de la matriz: ");
            fila = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de columnas: ");
            columna = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            tam = fila * columna;
            while (tam > 16)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EL TAMAÑO DE LAS FILAS ES INCORRECTO, DEBE SER MENOR QUE 16");
                break;
            }
            int[,] matriz = new int[fila, columna];

            while (tam < 16)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columna; j++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Introduce numeros menores a 600 y mayores a 200:");
                        matriz[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        while (matriz[i, j] >= 200 && matriz[i, j] <= 600);
                }
            }
```

EDIT:
Bueno he cambiado todo el codigo de una manera un poco mas practica y que se pueda entender mejor, ademas de que ya he podido solucionar el problemas, aqui lo adjunto:

```
            while (fila * columna >16)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("La matriz es muy grande, ingrese otros valores");

                System.Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de filas de la matriz: ");
                fila = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

                System.Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de columnas de la matriz: ");
                columna = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
             
                //Matriz para el ingreso de datos del usuario
            }
            int[,] matriz = new int[fila, columna];
            for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<columna; j++)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el numero de la posicion # "+ i, j);
                    int valor = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    //Si el valor no esta dentro del rango el usuario ingresara otro
                    while (valor < 200 | valor > 600)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("VALOR NO DENTRO DEL RANGO, INGRESE OTRO");
                        valor = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    matriz [i, j] = valor;
                }
```

Comment: @gbianchi si, justamente estaba viendo esos errores que me acabas de decir, pero para llenar la matriz no encuentro donde...

Comment: mirandolo bien hay montones de errores.. ahi te puse una respuesta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veo tantos errores no por novato.. si no por no leer tu codigo y no seguirlo paso a  paso que vamos a corregirlo...

```
while (tam > 16)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EL TAMAÑO DE LAS FILAS ES INCORRECTO, DEBE SER MENOR QUE 16");
    break;
}
```

Aca te estas fijando si el tamaño es mayor a 16... pero vamos a desglosar...

```
//Iteramos mientras el tamaño sea mayor a 16...
while (tam > 16)
{
    //Le mostramos un cartel al usuario
    Console.WriteLine("EL TAMAÑO DE LAS FILAS ES INCORRECTO, DEBE SER MENOR QUE 16");
    //salimos del while...
    break;
}
```

O sea... **NO HICIMOS NADA**

primero porque no modificamos tam dentro del while. Segundo porque salimos del while sin siquiera iterar... tercero porque dejamos pasar un dato erroneo...

Si hubieras querido que esto funcionara como corresponde, tal vez deberias pedir valores adentro de un while hasta que tam sea menor a 16...

Una vez que corrijas eso.. sigamos:

```
for(int i =0; i<fila; i++)
{
    for(int j= 0; i<columna; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa numeros de 200 a 600: ");
        matriz[fila, columna] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

La idea de los dos for esta perfecta... pero fijemosnos en el segundo for:

```
for(int j= 0; i<columna; i++)
```

Iteramos sobre j... pero aumentamos i?? y comparamos i???

Luego... entramos al for...

Si vas a poner una restriccion de valores, lo mejor seria comprobar que los valores estan bien no? por ejemplo usando [Int.TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

Y luego, dentro for, encontramos esto:

```
matriz[fila, columna] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Sacando el problema que puede haber errores como te marque antes (proba meter el numero 1 y pasa como si nada.. tambien el numero 113231412412 va a tirar un lindo error), fijate que estas insertando los valores no en la posicion de la matriz que estas recorriendo (con i y j).. si no que usas fila y columna, que son valores que ya usaste para definir el tamaño de la matriz.. o sea, siempre pones datos al final...

Mi recomendacion es que vayas leyendo el codigo de a poco, y lo vayas completando de a poco...

Y aprendas a hacer debug. muchos de estos errores se solucionan viendo tu codigo en tiempo real...

Comment: Vale si, lo he revisado pero sigo sin encontrar mi fallo, o no se si me explique mal. El usuario ingresara un numero para columnas, y el otro para filas, estos se guardan en la variable tam, ahora he puesto un While cuando tam es menor a 16, pero como logro hacer que esos 16 espacios los pueda rellenar uno por uno.

Comment: Empeza solucionando tu primero problema.. si en el primer input ingreso la letra a... tira error... si ingreso 24, funciona todo perfecto pero esta mal... que fallo no encontras si esta todo lleno de los errores que te marco aca? @JuanJesusCeron